# How to allocate memory at a specific location

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

This is for C.

I think malloc typically allocates the very next available space on the heap after the last allocation.

Is it possible to have malloc not do that and to choose where on the heap you'd like the memory to be allocated?

Is there any way in general to allocate memory on the heap and have it not be the very next address available but something "farther"?

Basically, my malloc'd space + more space is getting overwritten (as a test) so I'm losing the metadata associated with the malloc'd space since it is stored just next to the malloc'd space (even though I use a different malloc call).

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: For memory-management bugs try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (it is available on Linux and some other systems). And you think wrong about `malloc`. Read also about [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR). So in general **you cannot allocate memory at a specific location**. Tell us more about your operating system, compiler, libraries (including the standard C one) and your software.

Comment: What is meant by "overwritten (as a test)"? Do you mean you are overwriting on purpose, or overwriting during testing?

Comment: If your meta data is getting overwritten, I'd look to your code that is using the memory, likely in an improper fashion.  T'would be helpful to see that code.

Answer (score 2):

To temporarily work around memory corruption of blocks of memory allocated by `malloc`, simply allocate more memory than you normally need, so that your blocks are larger. This will give them more space for erroneous modifications before your program is adversely affected.

Do this **only** for temporary debugging purposes, so that you can investigate your program’s behavior while figuring out what is wrong.

Additionally, there are other techniques for analyzing improper memory accesses, including analyzers such as valgrind and debugger “watchpoint” features that interrupt a program and inform you when chosen locations are modified.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers. By test, I meant that it's for an assignment; however I didn't want to get too specific because I'm not asking for a solution, I just want to try to work with this idea I had about displacing some metadata.
I think the padding (allocating more memory) will work, thank you.
What's happening is basically that the test memcpy's the metadata to another location in memory, frees the pointer and then memcpy's the original data to its original location and tries to free again, therefore fooling the metadata into thinking it's ok to double free and then crashing.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff: I would not expect a `memcpy` implementation to rely solely on metadata stored in proximity to the allocated block. Managing memory allocation is a complicated problem (due in part to many different behavior patterns by diverse applications), so there are a variety of approaches. A memory allocator could keep its own database completely separate from the allocated blocks, keyed by address of the block. It may even have zones for different purposes and sizes of allocations, with different database methods used in different zones.

Comment: thanks Eric, that's really interesting. I wouldn't be able to implement something like this right now, but hopefully soon. I'll definitely keep in mind what you said.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to tell `malloc` where you want your space allocated on the heap.

Mostly the return value from `malloc` depends on two things: the version of `malloc` your library is using (there are many) and the size of the block allocated.

Comment: Also, sorry I should've mentioned the assignment thing right away to avoid confusion, it's my first time here I don't have a good feel yet for not crossing the line with that kind of stuff.

Thanks again.